Setting a booby trap for a thief which results in injury of the thief
Please consider the following hypothetical situation. A hypothetical person, Richard, owns a body shop. That is, he runs a business repair cars that have been damaged in an accident. In  his parking lot, he often has several cars that customers have brought in  for repair. He wants to safeguard these cars. As such, he puts up a 10 foot fence around the cars. In addition, around the fence, on the ground, he puts up barb wire. The barb wire is very hard to see especially at night with the lights off.
One night Joe, a car thief, climbs over the fence and jumps down into the barb wire.Joe could not see the barb wire because the parking lot was not well lit. Once there he cuts himself and is stuck. As a result, Joe has to call the police for help. The police arrive and then take Joe to the hospital. They also arrest him for attempting to steal a car and on the warrant he has outstanding for stealing a car.
Does Joe have a civil case against Larry?

Please do a quick search under "booby trap".

@MichaelHall But Richard hasn't attempted to conceal or camouflage the barbed-wire.

@PeterM If it's not easily visible, it's effectively hidden. A sign saying "Warning: barbed wire" might absolve him (assuming it's readable at night).

I think a car thief would force open the gate, if they want to steal a car.

@Barmar I've yet to see a barbed-wire topped fence anywhere that has a sign saying beware the barbed-wire.  And the barbed-wire on those fences are hard to see at night.

@PeterM the fence isn't topped with barbed wire: it's on the ground inside. Heaven help browsing buyers!

Right. I think of barbed wire inside the fence as like a guard dog. And it's common to have a sign warning of the latter.

@WeatherVane But IMHO it's a parallel scenario.  However, in the case that it's on the ground, unless Richard is very diligent, then the barbed-wire is severely overgrown with weeds.  But that raises the question, what if Richard and scattered various car parts around the inside part of his fence and let them be overgrown with weeds - perfect plausible deniability!

@Barmar It may be common, but is it necessary?  (My quick search shows that it depends on state law)

@PeterM I wonder what the law says if Joe falls from the fence and injures himself on the ground outside (not on the wire). Was the fence so high as to be dangerous? I think the difference is that the barbed wire is a deliberate trap.

@PeterM It varies by state: https://www.signs.com/blog/beware-of-dog-signs-protecting-you-your-dogs-and-your-visitors/

"But Richard hasn't attempted to conceal or camouflage the barbed-wire." A better example of not attempting to conceal it would be to put it at the top of the fence. Because if he puts barbed wire on the ground with the intent of making it "very hard to see especially at night with the lights off" then he has effectively set a trap. If you are instead asking about general liability for injuries to trespassers, then please edit the question to make it clear by removing any reference to a "trap." (and consider doing a search on that first...)

united-kingom
The Occupiers Liability Act 1984 obliges you to protect trespassers on your land from foreseeable harm. So erecting a deliberately harmful measure is illegal.
This page states

Should booby-traps be legal?
. . .
In 1996, 76-year-old William Newbery was sleeping in his tool shed to deter thieves when two men in their early 20s tried to force their way in. Mr Newbery fired a warning shot and accidentally injured one of them. Denied his haul of freebies and peppered with shotgun pellets, the assailant decided to sue his would-be victim on the grounds that he’d neglected his duty of care to trespassers, and won.


Court of Appeal judgment: Revill v Newbery [1995] EWCA Civ 10 (02 November 1995) https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/1995/10.html

@Lag at the top "This is an appeal by Mr. William Newbery", and at the bottom: "Order: appeal dismissed with costs; legal aid taxation of the respondent's costs; leave to appeal to the House of Lords refused."

I wasn't disputing anything in your answer, I provided the link in case you or anyone else were interested.
